# Trouble with QxtGlobalShortcut

Tags: c++, qt

I'm trying to set global shortcut for my applcation using QxtGlobalShortcut.
Here is my code:

```
QxtGlobalShortcut m_hotkeyHandle;

m_hotkeyHandle.setShortcut( QKeySequence("Ctrl+Shift+X") );
m_hotkeyHandle.setEnabled(true);

connect( &m_hotkeyHandle, SIGNAL(activated()),
        this, SLOT(hotkeyPressed()) );

void MainWindow::hotkeyPressed()
{
    QMessageBox::information(this, "Good", "Hot key triggered", "yes", "no");
}
```

But after applcation started i got:

> QxtGlobalShortcut failed to register:
>   "Ctrl+Shift+X"

And my programm doesn't activate after hot key pressing. What should i do?

Comment: Sorry, i don't understand what should i do? Are there any key to mask my question solved? Where is it?

Comment: Means that you need to copy the EDIT part to a new Answer, wait for 48 hours and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There was a bug in Qxt-lib 0.5 with shortcut. I spoke with developer and knew that i just need to update library from dev-branch (0.5.1 is worked).

Answer (score 0):

Can it be that another program has been tied to this global shortcut already?