# Can I add a global shortcut hook to a Qt application in Ubuntu?

Tags: linux, qt, ubuntu, hotkeys

My app lives in the tray and I want it to show its dialog in response of a global hotkey, like Google Desktop Search does, for example. It doesn't have to be cross platform.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Searching SO for *[qt] global hotkey* gives among other results this one:

[Trouble with QxtGlobalShortcut [solved]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1052691/trouble-with-qxtglobalshortcut-solved)

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu uses [GConf](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GConf) to store settings. It looks like Windows registry. [Those keys](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/ubuntu/assign-custom-shortcut-keys-on-ubuntu-linux/) are for storing global shortcuts. To set up global keybingings you should deal with GTK. So install those packages:

[image: App Centre]

And add to your `.pro` file following lines:

```
INCLUDEPATH += /usr/include/gconfmm-2.6\
                /usr/include/glibmm-2.4\
                /usr/lib/glibmm-2.4/include\
                /usr/include/glib-2.0\
                /usr/lib/glib-2.0/include\
                /usr/include/sigc++-2.0\
                /usr/lib/sigc++-2.0/include\
                /usr/include/gconf/2

LIBS += -L/usr/lib -lgconfmm-2.6
```

then you need to create new `.cpp` file or class besause you can't include Qt and GTK headers in the same file.

```
#include <gconfmm.h>
using namespace Gnome;
```

and the main part:

```
Conf::init();
    try
    {
        Glib::RefPtr<Conf::Client> pointer(Conf::Client::get_default_client());
        pointer->set("/apps/metacity/keybinding_commands/command_2",Glib::ustring("gedit"));
        pointer->set("/apps/metacity/global_keybindings/run_command_2",Glib::ustring("<Control><Alt>e"));
    }
    catch(Conf::Error error)
    {
        std::cerr << "Error code: " << error.code();
    }
```

You can use all predefined keys instead of `command_2` (there are `command_screenshot`, for example) and you can create your own keys such as

```
/apps/metacity/keybinding_commands/command_textedit
/apps/metacity/global_keybindings/run_command_textedit
```

but you also need to set up schemas for your custom keys (I don't know how to do it, I'm new to GTK). After code is executed shortcuts work well.